# Magento 2: Using nginx css js not loading

Tags: magento2.3.1, nginx, js-css

After installing  Nginx server Magento2.3.1 not working 
CSS js file not loading.

> etc/ngnix/ngnix.conf

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
    }

    http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


    #mail {
    #   # See sample authentication script at:
    #   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
    # 
    #   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
    #   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
    #   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
    # 
    #   server {
    #       listen     localhost:110;
    #       protocol   pop3;
    #       proxy      on;
    #   }
    # 
    #   server {
    #       listen     localhost:143;
    #       protocol   imap;
    #       proxy      on;
    #   }
    #}
```

> /var/www/html/magneto2/nginx.conf.sample

```
# Magento Vars
# set $MAGE_ROOT /path/to/magento/root;
# set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
#
# Example configuration:
# upstream fastcgi_backend {
#    # use tcp connection
#    # server  127.0.0.1;
#    # or socket
#    server   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
# }
# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name mage.dev;
#    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
#    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
#    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
# }


root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset off;

add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' 'nosniff';
add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1; mode=block';

location /setup {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location /update {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /pub {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
        expires max;
    }
    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ cron\.php {
    deny all;
}

location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=256M \n max_execution_time=600";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it not loading because of a 404 ?

Did you check if the file generation to `pub/static` works, means is it an issue with the loading, or already the generation ?

Is your magento installation in production mode, and if yes, did you regenerate the static content using `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`?

Did you check the file and folder permissions ?

Nginx Configuration is correctly set up, so the Webroot of nginx points to the /pub folder of the Magento Installation ?

Comment: site is in development mode, also deploying content hp bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy. and whole project permission is 777

Comment: can you also share the console output, maybe to see why the files cannot be located ?

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1/tradeplumbing-m2/pub/static/version1573828661/frontend/Tradeplumbingm2/Themem2/en_US/Amasty_Cart/css/vendor/owl.carousel.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The part of "/tradeplumbing" seems a bit wierd in the url.. is the setup of the urls in the store configuration correctly set up. If it is it could be also some kind of misconfiguration in nginx.
If both is not the case, i guess iam also out of ideas :(

Comment: The webroot path in the nginx configuration is maybe wrong, if i look that you got the /pub part inside your url. The webroot in your nginx should point to the pub folder inside the magento root

Comment: i have added my ngnix conf files also. please check my question

Answer (score 1):

This have been done in the same wrong way by many folks:

- NGINX config with `pub` as webroot (great)
- web URL includes `pub` in URLs (bad)

To explain it simply why it doesn't work for you: NGINX *root* is `pub` directory, so anything that starts with `/` is already in `pub`. When you put links that include `pub`, they are trying to load `/path/to/pub/pub/some/file` (which of course does not exist).

Proper config:

- NGINX config with `pub` as webroot
- web URL *without* `pub` in URLs

How to solve:

- Login to Magento admin (or adjust `core_config_data`) so that Base URL settings do not have `pub` inside them.
- Clean configuration cache

Comment: My base url's is already http://192.168.1.141/tradeplumbingm2/ and https://192.168.1.141/tradeplumbingm2/

Comment: Apparently it isn't as in one of your comments you mentioned `GET 127.0.0.1/tradeplumbing-m2/pub/static/version1573828661/… net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: it's console error

Comment: now , css jss loading but expcet home nothing load all shows 404  even amdin

Answer (score 1):

With all the above answers,

I had to change the **core_config_data** table's column values of `web/secure/use_in_frontend` & `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` to Zeero ( 0 ). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The project directory doesnt have the correct permission. Just

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magneto2/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/magneto2/
```